# Unable to deliver event. Exception follows. java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: fiware-cygnus

The exception I have:

```
 Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpBackend.createJsonResponse(HttpBackend.java:353)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpBackend.doRequest(HttpBackend.java:205)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpBackend.doRequest(HttpBackend.java:131)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.ckan.CKANBackendImpl.doCKANRequest(CKANBackendImpl.java:566)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.ckan.CKANBackendImpl.insert(CKANBackendImpl.java:178)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.ckan.CKANBackendImpl.persist(CKANBackendImpl.java:90)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICKANSink.persistAggregation(NGSICKANSink.java:525)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICKANSink.persistBatch(NGSICKANSink.java:260)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.processNewBatches(NGSISink.java:558)
        at com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink.process(NGSISink.java:370)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
```

My config looks like:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = ckan-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = ckan-channel

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = ckan-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder

cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSICKANSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.channel = ckan-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_host = //host//
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.ckan_port = //port//
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.api_key = //key//
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_size = 100
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_timeout = 30
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_ttl = 10
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.batch_retry_intervals = 5000
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.backend.max_conns = 500
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.backend.max_conns_per_route = 100
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.persistence_policy.max_records = 100
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.persistence_policy.expiration_time = 86400
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.ckan-sink.persistence_policy.checking_time = 600

cygnus-ngsi.channels.ckan-channel.type = memory
cygnus-ngsi.channels.ckan-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.ckan-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

So I'm using CKAN sink and I can see a package being successfully created in CKAN, but just no content in the resource. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!